# What is the proper way to setup a package with Spacemacs?

Tags: org-mode, init-file, spacemacs

I have been reading very good thing about Spacemacs, and decided to give it a try. Right now I am trying to port my (messy handwritten) configuration to it, and the Spacemacs way to do it is by creating a layer (or so I think).

And I have a few doubts:

1. I use `org-journal`, and it can only be loaded after `org`. What should I put in my `<layer>-packages` list? Just `org-journal` or both `org-journal` and `org`?
2. Where is the appropriate place to setup things like `org-agenda-files` and `org-todo-keywords`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can do both of these things: with, or without, a custom spacemacs layer.

Without a custom layer, you would add org-journal to the list of `dotspacemacs-additional-packages` (with `org` in your list of configuration layers). Your agenda and todo setup would go in `dotspacemacs/user-config`.

The other option would be to create your own custom layer for your org configuration. You'd put the org-journal requirement, and your agenda/todo configs in that layer. If you haven't, checkout the spacemacs layer introduction [here](http://spacemacs.org/doc/LAYERS.html). Regarding your comment that layers are the "Spacemacs way", that may be the Spacemacs philosophy, but it's not a functional requirement. Loading individual packages and keeping all your config in your .spacemacs would definitely work to get spacemacs configured how you like. A custom configuration layer could come later (so says a person who doesn't have any custom layers yet, but a fair amount of configuration).